# Error: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io

I am using webdriverIO v7 (latest stable version) and cucumber.
I get that error: `Error: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received undefined`
This is the stack trace:

```
2021-04-08T18:29:37.403Z ERROR @wdio/runner: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:120:11)
    at Object.relative (path.js:437:5)
    at getDefinitionLineAndUri (C:\my-project\node_modules\cucumber\lib\support_code_library_builder\build_helpers.js:184:27)
    at buildStepDefinitionConfig (C:\my-project\node_modules\cucumber\lib\support_code_library_builder\build_helpers.js:124:7)
    at SupportCodeLibraryBuilder.defineStep (C:\my-project\node_modules\cucumber\lib\support_code_library_builder\index.js:51:79)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\my-project\src\step_definitions\/accountSummary_steps.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Module._compile (C:\my-project\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\my-project\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.hookedLoader [as _load] (C:\my-project\node_modules\mockery\mockery.js:111:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at C:\my-project\node_modules\@wdio\cucumber-framework\build\index.js:204:13
```

In my accountSummary_steps.js on line 6 is only this:

```
    import loggedInHeaderModule from "../pages/modules/loggedInHeaderModule"
    import accountSummaryPage from "../pages/accountSummaryPage"

import {Then, When} from 'cucumber';
    When(/^I click on My account details link$/, function () { // This is line 6
        loggedInHeaderModule.openAccountSummary();
    });
```

This is my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.5.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.0",
    "@types/cucumber": "^7.0.0",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.3.1",
    "@wdio/config": "^7.3.1",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.3.1",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.3.1",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.3.1",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.3.1",
    "@wdio/sync": "^7.3.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "eslint-plugin-wdio": "^7.0.0",
    "file-system": "^2.2.2",
    "mjpeg-consumer": "^2.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "webdriverio": "^7.3.1",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.3.1",
    "@wdio/browserstack-service": "^7.3.1",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^7.3.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "forever": "^3.0.4",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
```

Anybody has any idea what went wrong there?
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to resolve it by removing `"cucumber": "^6.0.5"` dependency and using `"@cucumber/cucumber": "^7.1.0"` instead in `package.json` file.
In my steps file I imported statements like this:

```
import {Then, When} from '@cucumber/cucumber';
```

Instead of this:

```
import {Then, When} from 'cucumber';
```

It seems it is the new way how webdriverIO v7 is integarted with cucumber. (Like described here in [docs](https://webdriver.io/blog/2021/02/09/webdriverio-v7-released/#cucumber-v7-update))

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with this with cucumber, I got that same error. After endless fidling, I found that the package lock file looked different - it had node_modules prefacing all the dependencies.  The Cucumber I was using couldnt handle this. This was related to npm, I downgraded npm to < 7. Then I found

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```

which updated the package lock file with the previous formatting.

At that point I was able to run npm i to reload cucumber. Worked after that.